# WebRTC video works with other hosting sites, but not Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, video, webrtc

Good day!

I have a WebRTC application with Socket.io for signalling. I have a STUN/TURN configuration that passes the test https://test.webrtc.org/

So far, the WebRTC part of my application is tested(multiple times) on:

- **Localhost, same machine, multiple tabs**: Everything working, video and audio
- **Local network**: Everything working, video and audio
- **Firebase, different public IP addresses**: Everything works, video and audio
- **Heroku, different public IP addresses:** ICE failed, or TURN error

The exact error message is:

'ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken'

On other platforms, it works, not needing the TURN server, but not on Heroku, where it fails completely.

Why is this? Is Heroku doing something that interferes with the WebRTC connection initialization? Socket.io is working fine, and there are no error on the server, so the issue is most likely on establishing the peer-to-peer connection.

**UPDATE:**

This is the logs from the failed WebRTC connection. As you can see, it has an offer, an answer, and also the ice candidates, but I don't know why there is still an error 'ICE connection failed'

```
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.024Z create":"([{"iceServers":[{"urls":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},{"urls":"stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478"},{"urls":"stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302"}],"sdpSemantics":"unified-plan"}])"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.025Z - get _peerConnectionId":"{}"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.029Z onnegotiationneeded":"({})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.066Z onsignalingstatechange":"("have-local-offer")"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.067Z - get signalingState":""have-local-offer""
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.068Z - get signalingState":""have-local-offer""
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.068Z - get signalingState (1)":""have-local-offer""
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.083Z onicegatheringstatechange":"("gathering")"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.083Z - get iceConnectionState":""new""
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.083Z - get iceGatheringState":""gathering""
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.083Z onicecandidate":"({"candidate":"candidate:0 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.254.103 48433 typ host","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b5a93693"})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.084Z onicecandidate":"({"candidate":"candidate:4 1 UDP 2122252543 2001:fd8:3292:7e8a:372b:ff13:dcc:d459 52481 typ host","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b5a93693"})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.084Z onicecandidate (1)":"({"candidate":"candidate:8 1 TCP 2105458943 192.168.254.103 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b5a93693"})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.084Z onicecandidate (2)":"({"candidate":"candidate:9 1 TCP 2105524479 2001:fd8:3292:7e8a:372b:ff13:dcc:d459 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b5a93693"})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.125Z onicecandidate":"({"candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 1685987327 180.190.42.104 58922 typ srflx raddr 192.168.254.103 rport 48433","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b5a93693"})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.157Z onicecandidate":"({"candidate":"candidate:2 1 UDP 1685987071 180.190.42.104 58923 typ srflx raddr 192.168.254.103 rport 48433","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b5a93693"})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.270Z onicecandidate":"({"candidate":"candidate:3 1 UDP 1685986815 180.190.42.104 58924 typ srflx raddr 192.168.254.103 rport 48433","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b5a93693"})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.405Z onicecandidate":"({"candidate":"","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b5a93693"})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.406Z onicegatheringstatechange":"("complete")"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.406Z - get iceConnectionState":""new""
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.407Z - get iceGatheringState":""complete""
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.407Z onicecandidate":"({})"
"2020-10-07T10:15:52.410Z - get localDescription":"{"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-81.0.1 6937478949161186100 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 10:C8:69:1A:90:BA:59:81:85:97:53:D1:DD:9C:3A:85:E5:EC:F5:99:05:C7:39:B4:5F:1F:0C:FD:BD:A3:5C:F2\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=application 58922 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 180.190.42.104\r\na=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.254.103 48433 typ host\r\na=candidate:4 1 UDP 2122252543 2001:fd8:3292:7e8a:372b:ff13:dcc:d459 52481 typ host\r\na=candidate:8 1 TCP 2105458943 192.168.254.103 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=candidate:9 1 TCP 2105524479 2001:fd8:3292:7e8a:372b:ff13:dcc:d459 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=candidate:1 1 UDP 1685987327 180.190.42.104 58922 typ srflx raddr 192.168.254.103 rport 48433\r\na=candidate:2 1 UDP 1685987071 180.190.42.104 58923 typ srflx raddr 192.168.254.103 rport 48433\r\na=candidate:3 1 UDP 1685986815 180.190.42.104 58924 typ srflx raddr 192.168.254.103 rport 48433\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\na=ice-pwd:421e15dcbf777c9168d76225d6b88a25\r\na=ice-ufrag:b5a93693\r\na=mid:0\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=max-message-size:1073741823\r\n"}"
"2020-10-07T10:15:59.806Z onsignalingstatechange":"("stable")"
"2020-10-07T10:15:59.807Z - get signalingState":""stable""
"2020-10-07T10:15:59.807Z - get signalingState (1)":""stable""
"2020-10-07T10:15:59.808Z - get signalingState":""stable""
"2020-10-07T10:15:59.809Z - get remoteDescription":"{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 808825067375462440 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS\r\nm=application 60687 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 130.105.206.24\r\nb=AS:30\r\na=candidate:1434301788 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.10 60687 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10\r\na=candidate:2741881992 1 udp 1686052607 130.105.206.24 60687 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.10 rport 60687 generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10\r\na=candidate:469649836 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.0.10 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 9D:92:A5:1E:AA:7B:B2:4C:E0:5E:05:1B:18:E4:07:49:24:99:DE:8A:68:B1:F9:D3:99:81:53:AB:E3:C4:D5:18\r\na=ice-pwd:gLoMECMjqHsVB5mjiA75kWBq\r\na=ice-ufrag:6Doj\r\na=mid:0\r\na=setup:active\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=max-message-size:262144\r\n"}"
"2020-10-07T10:15:59.811Z oniceconnectionstatechange":"("checking")"
"2020-10-07T10:15:59.811Z - get iceConnectionState":""checking""
"2020-10-07T10:15:59.811Z - get iceGatheringState":""complete""
"2020-10-07T10:16:10.928Z oniceconnectionstatechange":"("failed")"
"2020-10-07T10:16:10.928Z - get iceConnectionState":""failed""
"2020-10-07T10:16:10.929Z - get iceGatheringState":""complete""
}
```

Comment: Provide entire build.log as well as the normal log when spinning up the dyno. Just copying snippets out of it is not really useful.

Comment: @TinNguyen I edited the post, but instead of heroku logs, I appended the WebRTC debugging logs.

Comment: Those logs aren't helpful. Provide the entire build.log from Heroku as well as the normal Heroku.log starting from the moment you turn on your Heroku web process until the error occurs.